# Asciimatics как прервать анимацию

Tags: python

При выполнении кода в консоли появляется красивая анимация. 
Как прервать эту анимацию и снова вернуться к обычной консоли и выполнению консольных функций?

Мой код:

```
from asciimatics.renderers import FigletText, Fire
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.effects import Print
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError
from pyfiglet import Figlet
import sys
from time import sleep
import os

def demo(screen):
    screen.set_title("24rc bot by Morty")
    scenes = []
    text = Figlet(font="banner", width=200).renderText("123")
    width = max([len(x) for x in text.split("\n")])
    effects = [
        Print(screen,
              Fire(screen.height, 85, text, 0.4, 40, screen.colours),
              0,
              speed=1,
              transparent=False),
        Print(screen,
              FigletText("123", "banner"),
              screen.height - 9, x=(screen.width - width) // 2 + 1,
              colour=Screen.COLOUR_BLACK,
              bg=Screen.COLOUR_BLACK,
              speed=1),
        Print(screen,
              FigletText("123", "banner"),
              screen.height - 9,
              colour=Screen.COLOUR_BLACK,
              bg=Screen.COLOUR_RED,
              speed=1),

    ]
    scenes.append(Scene(effects, -1))
    screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=True)


Screen.wrapper(demo)
```

Comment: Судя по описанию функции [play](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/asciimatics.html?highlight=unhandled_input#asciimatics.screen.Screen.play) достаточно нажать Q или X

Comment: При нажатии Q или X программа закрываеться

Comment: Если добавить в конце, например, `print('Hello!')` и `input()`, то при нажатии Q или X выведет `Hello!` и не закроется.